# Can' static method in java, it returns null

Tags: java, static-methods

I'm trying to access a static method in a Utils class I created:

```
 public class Utils{

 public static Date convertToDate(String dateString, String dFormat){

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(dFormat, Locale.US);

    Date convertedDate;
    try {
        convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
        Log.i("date", "convertedDate =  " + convertedDate);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    return convertedDate;

}
 }
```

When I attempted to access this method like so:

```
 Utils.convertToDate("03-04-2012", "mm-dd-yyyy");
```

I get a null pointer exception.

How could this be???

Comment: Could it be your Log that is not initialized?

Comment: On a side note, I think you may mean `MM` and not `mm` : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: @Atma nobody can really help you because you have not posted the stack trace. The full error output is incredibly helpful in determining the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that it's not *that* method that's throwing the exception - but the fact that it returns null and you're using the return value, like this:

```
Date date = Utils.convertToDate("03-04-2012", "mm-dd-yyyy");
System.out.println(date.toString());
```

That's the problem with effectively swallowing exceptions and pretending nothing's wrong. Note that your format should be "MM-dd-yyyy" instead of "mm-dd-yyyy". Also note that your code would be simpler if you declared `convertedDate` within your `try` block and just returned it, instead of waiting to come out of the `try` block before returning.

(Having said all of this, I wouldn't have *expected* that code to throw an exception. It wouldn't give you the value you wanted, but it should be okay to actually parse... If you could produce a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, that would really help.)

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
Utils.convertToDate("03-04-2012", "MM-dd-yyyy");
```

since `mm` represents the minutes, while `MM` represents the month.

Comment: the power of john skeet beats you by 12 seconds.

Comment: @Kevin I will never beat Jon in either way ;)

Comment: its okay, he just beated me by 1 minute to on another question